# change index inside a for loop

Tags: java, for-loop, indexing

Am I able to change the index inside the for loop in java? For example:

```
for (int j = 0; j < result_array.length; j++){
            if (item==" ") {
                result_array[j] = "%";
                result_array[j+1] = "2";
                result_array[j+2] = "0";
                j = j+2;
            }
            else result_array[j] = item;
        }
```

Although it is doing j++ in the for loop, inside the for loop, i am also doing j = j + 3. Is it possible for me to achieve this?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "is it possible?" It is possible, and you've done it.

Comment: It is conceptually wrong to do that...

Comment: Avoid `==` when comparing Strings (or any objects) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java

Comment: Yes, but you might accidentally confuse yourself.

Comment: @MichaelMyers nah.. the code above is wrong. I should have used while loop

Comment: @WendyMunmunWang: He's not saying anything about the correctness of the code, but about the question 'whether it is possible'. Correctness of the code also depends on whether it does what you're expecting (semantics) in addition to what you can do in code (syntax). Syntactically your code is correct, and your wordings make the question mean more about syntax than semantics.

Comment: Off topic: An early 3rd GL was FORTRAN. Its design was influenced by a particular computer's machine instructions. The loop construct was `DO LINE INDEX = START, LIMIT, INCR`, where LINE was the label of last line of code in the loop, START was the initial value, LIMIT was the terminating value, and INCR was the increment value. Changing the values of INDEX, START, LIMIT, or INCR while the loop was running would have no effect until the loop exited.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes you can change index inside a for loop but it is too confusing. Better use a while loop in such case.

```
int j = 0;
while (j < result_array.length) {
    if (item.equals(" ")) {
        result_array[j] = "%";
        result_array[j + 1] = "2";
        result_array[j + 2] = "0";
        j = j + 2;
    } else
        result_array[j] = item;
    j++;
}
```