# To Reduce a String

Tags: java, string, stringbuilder

I was solving a problem to reduce the form to it's non-reducible form. This was the question.

> Shil has a string S , consisting of N lowercase English letters. In one operation, he can delete any pair of adjacent letters with same value. For example, string "aabcc" would become either "aab" or "bcc" after  operation.

> Shil wants to reduce S as much as possible. To do this, he will repeat the above operation as many times as it can be performed. Help Shil out by finding and printing 's non-reducible form!

> If the final string is empty, print Empty String; otherwise, print the final non-reducible string.

> Sample Input 0

> **aaabccddd**

> Sample Output 0

> **abd**

> Sample Input 1

> **baab**

> Sample Output 1

> **Empty String**

> Sample Input 2

> **aa**

> Sample Output 2

> **Empty String**

Explanation

Sample Case 0:
Shil can perform the following sequence of operations to get the final string:

Thus, we print .

Sample Case 1:
Shil can perform the following sequence of operations to get the final string:
**aaabccddd -> abccddd**

**abccddd   -> abddd**

**abddd     -> abd**

Thus we print **abd**

Sample case 1:
**baab -> bb**

**bb   -> Empty String.**

And what I have done till now is try to solve it through StringBuilder in Java.But some of testcases pass while other's don't and I can't find out what's the error?

> Here is the code that I have tried so far.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Solution {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(scan.nextLine());
    for(int i = 0; i < sb.length()-1; i++)
        {
            if(sb.charAt(i) == sb.charAt(i+1))
                sb.delete(i,i+2);
                i  = 0;
        }
    if(sb.length() == 0)
        System.out.println("Empty String");
    else
        System.out.println(sb.toString());
}
```

}

Inputs like  **aaabccddd**

and **aa** pass.But when the input is **baab** it fails.

Comment: I ran your program and it seems to be printing output as "bb" for your input string "baab"

Comment: It is a _challenge_, but here's a solution from github https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/reduced-string and https://github.com/shengmin/coding-problem/tree/master/hackerrank/string-reduction

Comment: Shouldn't "baab" produce "b" ?

Comment: No it should print Empty String in case of "baab".

Comment: I am solving the challenge from there itself.But I don't want to see the solution.I need to know if I can solve by this method which i am trying and if so what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use a while loop. Problem with your code is that it just iterate through the code just one time. In first iteration though your input "baab" becomes "bb", then it checks 2nd b and try to find a "b" in i+1 (which does not exist). change your for loop to a while loop as below.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Solution{
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(scan.nextLine());
    int c=0;

    while(c< sb.length()-1){
        if(sb.charAt(c) == sb.charAt(c+1)){
            sb.delete(c,c+2);
            c=0;
        }
        else{
            c+=1;
        }
    }
    if(sb.length() == 0)
        System.out.println("Empty String");
    else
        System.out.println(sb.toString());
}
```

}

Comment: I have edited the code and added i =0 in the loop so that it checks the first b again.Can you check it?If that could be a valid process?

Comment: Sure I will check that. please give me a moment.

Comment: You are welcome.  According to this post it is too confusing to change index inside for loop. So it is better if you use while loop for that. [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30088401/change-index-inside-a-for-loop) .  .

Comment: Ok, one thing why did you use  "change" variable here? I just couldn't understand it's use.

Comment: That can be removed. I changed that in the answer.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you just run loop through the string for one time.
For example:
String "baab", you just delete "aa" and finish the loop.

Solution: use recursion with a flag isNonReducible, loop until it give empty string or flag isNonReducible = true;

```
public class Solution {
public static StringBuilder checkReducible(StringBuilder sb) {
    boolean isNonReducible = true;
    for (int i = 0; i < sb.length() - 1; i++) {
        if (sb.charAt(i) == sb.charAt(i + 1)) {
            isNonReducible = false;
            sb.delete(i, i + 2);    
        }
    }
    if (sb.length() == 0) {
        return new StringBuilder("Empty String");
    }
    else {
        if(!isNonReducible) {
            sb = checkReducible(sb);
        }
        return sb; 
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(scan.nextLine());
    System.out.println(checkReducible(sb));
    scan.close();
}
}
```

Comment: Your code just right when the string has only one reducible substring.

Comment: Hey the code is working fine.But let me just understand how it's working.Thank you very much though..:)

Answer (score 0):

you can do with the help of lable try this,

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
     boolean canReduce = true;
     Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
     StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(scan.nextLine());


     startPoint: while (sb.length() > 0 && canReduce) {
        for (int i = 0; i < sb.length() - 1; i++) {
            if (sb.charAt(i) == sb.charAt(i + 1)) {
                sb.delete(i, i + 2);
                canReduce=true;
                 continue startPoint;
            }else{
                canReduce=false;
            }

        }
    }

    if (sb.length() == 0) {

        System.out.println("Empty String");
    } else {

        System.out.println(sb.toString());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    StringBuilder sb =new StringBuilder(in.nextLine());

   for (int i=0; i<sb.length()-1; i++){
        if(sb.charAt(i)==sb.charAt(i+1)){
            sb.delete(i, i+2);
            i=-1;

     }
    }
    if(sb.length()==0){
        System.out.println("Empty String");
    }else{
        System.out.println(sb);
    }
   }
```